# how to remove datetime error in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i make an entity in symfony2 and i set the entity as createddatetime and updateddatetime,but when i used setter in controller the error occur like this

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\QuickBacklog\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType.php line 44
```

and here is my code of entity:

```
/**
     * Set createdDatetime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdDatetime
     * @return Sections
     */
    public function setCreatedDatetime($createdDatetime)
    {
        $this->createdDatetime = $createdDatetime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdDatetime
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreatedDatetime()
    {
        return $this->createdDatetime;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedDatetime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedDatetime
     * @return Sections
     */
    public function setUpdatedDatetime($updatedDatetime)
    {
        $this->updatedDatetime = $updatedDatetime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedDatetime
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedDatetime()
    {
        return $this->updatedDatetime;
    }
```

but when i write in controller

```
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$entity->setCreatedDatetime($date);
$entity->setUpdatedDatetime($date);
```

the error occurs how i remove this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`updatedDatetime` and `createddatetime` need to be objects of `DateTime` class.

so your controller code should be something like:

```
$date= new \DateTime();
$entity->setCreatedDatetime($date);
$entity->setUpdatedDatetime($date);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other post mentions, your entity expect the type to be `DateTime`, but I feel like an additional bit of information but help you out in the future.

With doctrine, you can add events (such as `prePersist`), so you could add a function called `setDefaultCreatedDatetime` which would look like:

```
public function setDefaultCreatedDatetime()
{
    $this->setCreatedDatetime(new \DateTime());
}
```

you can then add:

```
lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [setDefaultCreatedDatetime]
```

to your doctrine entity. This will save you having to call this method manually.

You can also do the same for your `setUpdatedTime` and use the `preUpdate` event.